# How do I fix continuity issues with my texture if its mesh is made up of 4 other meshes joined together?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

I've had to remodel a gun in order to apply textures to it (was made in roblox studio), and after modeling this gun I joined some meshes that would be the same colour + texture in roblox studio so as to minimize the amount of meshes necessary to assemble a gun. When trying to apply a procedural texture to one of my joined meshes (made up of 4 meshes), I noticed there were some discontinuations within the texture, like some sort of borders were applied to it. I thought that when joining meshes, the texture would apply itself throughout the whole mesh, but evidently I'm wrong. I've tried remodeling it all based from one mesh, but that was very frustrating and didn't yield any results. What are some possible solutions to this problem?[image: Here's an image of the textured mesh consisting of 4 joined meshes.]
[image: Here's the node setup for this texture, FYI the scale value has been increased since taking this picture, I don't remember the value for the first image]

Comment: The texture mapping really depends on how you UV unwrap the mesh, remodelling the whole thing is unlikely to help. Also try using Object coordinates instead of UV coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using object coordinates was exactly what I needed to do.